# An adjective for "able to see the big picture"

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

Is there a formal word to describe someone who sees not just the particulars, but also the bigger picture?

Comment: A Gestalt psychologist, hehe.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have never come across a term which explicitly means "seeing not just particulars, but also the whole", without any other connotations.  There are several words which come close to that concept, though.

**Perceptive**, **perspicacious**, **insightful**, or  **sagacious** could be a good fit for what you're looking for.

**Sharp** or **shrewd** imply quick grasping of a situation.

**Clairvoyant** means that one can see beyond what the normal human senses can register, though it is often used in a context of mysticism.  Not always.

**Holistic**, suggested by @brachomonacho, can be close, but it has some connotations that you might not want.  Among other things, it often means *complete* or *whole*.  See the [thesaurus.com entry](http://thesaurus.com/browse/holistic?__utma=1.1015376757.1309796641.1310484825.1310563942.30&__utmb=1.14.9.1310565207974&__utmc=1&__utmx=-&__utmz=1.1310563942.30.5.utmcsr=dictionary.reference.com%7Cutmccn=%28referral%29%7Cutmcmd=referral%7Cutmcct=/&__utmv=-&__utmk=42958245).

Comment: Perspicacious is my personal favorite, since it encompasses both insight and understanding (such as one would need to "see the big picture").

Comment: I like [sagacious](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/sagacious), personally.

Answer (score 5):

I was just about to suggest ***visionary***... But seeing as Harrold has beaten me to it, what about ***holistic***?

Comment: _Holistic_ has a bit of a metaphysical or spiritual connotation in that context, as you'll see if you check it out in a dictionary.  Not sure if the OP was looking for that sort of thing.  But certainly, I don't see that it can't work.  Good spot!

Comment: @drm65: I was under the impression that ***holistic*** is, these days, seeing increased usage over a range of contexts highly divergent from topics of metaphysical or spiritual philosophy...
I've often heard people use the word in general statements such as "to take a more holistic approach/view..." and "this person's assessment is considerably holistic".

Comment: I've seen that too, which is why I said it might work.  But my experience is localized, and the dictionary is less so.

Answer (score 2):

**Generalist**

> A person with a broad general knowledge, especially one with more than
>   superficial knowledge in several areas and the ability to combine
>   ideas from diverse fields.

Reference is [this wiktionary page](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/generalist).

Comment: Even a "person with a broad general _knowledge_" might not be able to _see_ any more than normal.  That is an implication indirectly related to the subject of the question.

Answer (score 2):

There are several phrases, particularly common in "biz-speak," that refer directly to this quality. To wit:

"He's a [big-picture](http://www.davealpert.com/blog/?p=37) kind of guy. He sees things above the clouds. He can give you the elevator view."

Also, a big +1 to Ivo Rossi's contribution of "generalist," which usually means someone who isn't possessed of a great deal of granular information, but is good at seeing how various items relate to each other in a macro-level way.

Comment: +1 for "big picture".  (I don't agree on "generalist".)

Answer (score 2):

*Strategist* or *strategic planner* is the word to describe the person with the eye on the big picture.

Answer (score 1):

**[Visionary](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/visionary?region=us)** is the word.

Comment: **Visionary** means having foresight, not seeing the whole.

Comment: @KarsusRen: Yes, but I think that the best visionaries tend to be those who can always see the 'bigger picture', as opposed to those with a *miopic* tendency.

Comment: @Karsus Ren I can not see how does predicting based on awareness of future events differs from "seeing the whole". I understand that it is not exactly the same but these two qualities usually come together and are rather similar.

Comment: @brachomonacho Indeed.

Comment: Again here, as with _generalist_, the word merely _implies_ above-average perception; it does not _mean_ it.  It usually means that the person in question has big dreams, for better or for worse; not necessarily increased perspicaciousness.

Comment: @brachomonacho: That argument is illogical.  Just because the best of a group has a certain strength, it does not mean that the group _is_ the embodiment of that strength.  IOW, just because the best visionaries are aided by acute perception, it does not mean that all those with acute perception are visionaries.