# A single word for "not seeing the big picture"

Tags: single-word-requests, idioms, adjectives

I am looking for a word that would describe being obsessed with the details of a larger entity such that the "looker" neglects to see the whole or (perhaps more importantly) the *purpose* of the whole.

Basically, "not seeing the big picture".

What can [more] succinctly describe this?

**Edit:** I just found this post: [An adjective for "able to see the big picture"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/34068/an-adjective-for-able-to-see-the-big-picture). I think I want the exact opposite.

Comment: You want a single word for "can't see the wood for the trees?" Hmm...

Comment: If there were a word, why would the idiom have been invented in the first place? Seriously. There's no such word.

Comment: @Kris It's also possible that there is a word, and you just don't know it.  For example, you haven't provided an answer.

Comment: "A single word for “not seeing the big picture”" -  Republican, lol.

Comment: narrow minded, comes to mind. (Ha ha to Daniel. :)]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

How about **myopic**, which means short-sighted and therefore, both literally and figuratively not able to see the big picture?

Comment: That's about distance, not width, Ha!

Comment: @Kris Perhaps I did not phrase the question properly, and Brad's answer does not seem to be an adequate answer to some readers such as yourself, but this was exactly the word I was looking for.

Comment: @Kris, If a person is myopic, they are forced to focus at the up close. While focusing on a near object, one loses sight of those things in the periphery. This is the perfect answer for both literal and figurative short-sightedness. (Of course, "short-sighted" works too, especially if you are unsure if your audience will understand "myopic")

Answer (score 8):

*Shortsighted, tunnel-vision, hyper-focused, myopic*, or *unimaginative* can all apply to this. As well as *detail-oriented, anal, drudgeon*, or *dullard*.

Answer (score 4):

What about *omphalocentric*, i.e. navel-gazing?

Comment: I like that. Not a word I'd ever use, but a good word to know :)

Answer (score 4):

How about "blinkered" (when a horse if forced to only see what is in front of them).

Answer (score 0):

**Unholistic**

It depends on the context, but you could use it to refer to an approach that does not consider a holistic way.

Which means: characterized by comprehension of the parts of something as intimately interconnected and explicable only by reference to the whole.

Answer (score 0):

**parochial** and its synonyms

[Collins English Dictionary](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/parochial)

Answer (score 0):

Tunnel vision.  That's when you get so focused on a single goal that you fail to see anything to your left or right.  And that's all stuff that can easily derail your entire project.

Comment: Note: the person who asked the question is looking for a single-word answer. Tunnel vision captures the idea of "not seeing the big picture" but doesn't satisfy the asker's request

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the context but I think one who is incapable of "seeing the big picture or understanding the entirety of a situation may be considered Obtuse.

ob·tuse
/əbˈt(y)o͞os,äbˈt(y)o͞os/Submit
adjective
adjective: obtuse
1.
annoyingly insensitive or slow to understand.
"he wondered if the doctor was being deliberately obtuse"
synonyms:   stupid, dull, slow-witted, slow, dull-witted, unintelligent, witless, half-baked, halfwitted, doltish, lumpish, blockish, imperceptive; More
ant

Answer (score 0):

You might say 'one-eyed', which is used similarly to 'myopic'.

[lacking breadth of vision : narrow in outlook](http://lacking%20breadth%20of%20vision%20:%20narrow%20in%20outlook)

Answer (score -1):

not seeing the big picture is "gestalt challenged."  :)

Comment: We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.