# A word for someone who always looks at the bigger picture

Tags: single-word-requests

What is a formal word to describe someone who looks at the bigger picture

Comment: What do you mean by 'bigger picture?". Please elaborate your question.

Comment: That can be a positive trait or sometimes a negative trait.  Can you provide a little more context such as using it in a sentence (leaving the word in question as a blank).

Comment: similar to [this](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/34068/an-adjective-for-able-to-see-the-big-picture) question.

Comment: " Theorician "  ?

Comment: Context is key.  Could be *strategist*, *pragmatist* or just *philosopher.*

Comment: _Forest seer_ might work.

Answer (score 1):

"hedgehog".  From an ancient Greek fragment attributed to Archilochus: πόλλ' οἶδ' ἀλώπηξ, ἀλλ' ἐχῖνος ἓν μέγα ("a fox knows many things, but a hedgehog one important thing").  See [The Hedgehog and the Fox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hedgehog_and_the_Fox).

Comment: An interesting candidate, but we should add a caveat that this probably  wouldn't count as a "formal word." I've never heard anyone say at a meeting, "We need to get Greg in here, he's a real hedgehog, and we need someone who can see the bigger picture." Still, it's an interesting option that's worth mentioning.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know of any specific word for this kind of person, "generalist" would come to mind as someone who takes a general view of things.